# "error": "message": "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, macos, postman

So, I'm trying to create a route and I created a route that should manage to POST data and I have been testing it in postman. It looks like a lot of people have got the same problem, but I have not been able to find a solution. I can see the name hasn't got a value but I've also seen a video where it should work with that bit of code. The person I've seen gets the response as JSON in postman, mine gives me the message shown underneath.

**My code:**

```
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    const user = {
        name: req.body.name,
        eMail: req.body.eMail
    };
    res.status(201).json({
        message: 'Handling user',
        createdUser: user
    });
});
```

[image: My code]

**The answer I get from postman:**

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"
    }
}
```

[image: The answer I get from postman]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using express. Are you using a body parser? Without one, `req.body` will always be undefined, which looks like your issue. Try putting this before you define any of your routes.

```js
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
```

[Docs](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req.body)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is going to help you or not but you can refer to this post
[https://medium.com/coding-at-dawn/how-to-check-for-undefined-in-javascript-bcedd62c8ad#:~:text=An%20undefined%20value%20in%20JavaScript,so%20we%20call%20it%20undefined%20](https://medium.com/coding-at-dawn/how-to-check-for-undefined-in-javascript-bcedd62c8ad#:%7E:text=An%20undefined%20value%20in%20JavaScript,so%20we%20call%20it%20undefined%20).